# How to avoid empty values from checkbox list by using EntityType form type?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have a form field like this:

```
$form->add('tags', EntityType:class, array(
    'class' => Tags::class,
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'required' => true,
));
```

This render a nice checkbox list and I need to ensure that at least one option is selected after submiting the form, but even if the `required` option is `true` it doesn't work, I tried with `NotBlank()` and `NotNull()` constraints, also doesn't work (i.e. the form is valid).

**How to avoid empty values from checkbox list by using `EntityType` form type?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Count constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html).

In your entity class:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Count(
 *      min = "1",
 *      minMessage = "You must specify at least one tag"
 * )
 */
protected $tags
```

Note that you can specify a `max` parameter and the according message.

Also, the `required` option only add `required` to your field on the client side, it does nothing on the server side.